# Why does FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() returns nil on my device but works fine in the iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

In my IOS9 application I use the Facebook SDK 4.7.0 graph api to search for public places.

I use the FBSDKApplicationDelegate in my apps delegate which I believe provides me with valid app access token (since I don't use any user specific data an application login is sufficient for me).

When I call FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() in my ViewController to check if the token is valid I always succeed in the simulator but not when deployed on the real device.

Any suggestions?

I have followed the new ios9 guide and provided the additional info in my plist.
Since my application is still in development my Facebook companion app (which holds my app id and secret) are still not available for general public. Could this be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

for checking facebook permission..& give a permission...if permission exist then automatically get accesstoken other wise ask for login...

**For Swift**

```
 var login: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
login.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email"], handler: { (result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

  if (error != nil)
  {
        //Process error
   }
   else if result.isCancelled
   {
        //Handle cancellations
   }
  else
  {
        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
        // should check if specific permissions missing
        if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email"){
            //Do work
   }
     }
   })
```

**For Objective c:**

check Permission like this. following code use ..

```
if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]hasGranted:@"email"])
   {
      // add your coding here after login call this block automatically.
   }
   else
   {

//login code  **//if accesstoken expired...then call this block**

FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

[loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)




  }];

   }
```

Comment: Thanks Maulik! Your suggestion let my application redirect to a Facebook web login, but I don't want any user interaction and for the search I want to do I don't need a user login.
When I start the app in the simulator it just works fine and I get my list of places!

Comment: I appreciate your quick response Maulik but it doesn't really answer my question. There are different kind of access tokens and for the app access token (the one I want to use) you do not need to let the user login with his account on Facebook.
And I still don't know why I get the places in the simulator and not on the devices

Comment: you can't get any accesstoken without login